# Create query to unwind array and filter out elements after an element with a certain value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document like this in a collection:

```
{ 
  _id: '123', 
  locations: [ 
    {uuid:'1-1'}, 
    {uuid:'2-2'}, 
    {uuid:'3-3'}, 
    {uuid:'4-4'} 
  ] 
}
```

I would like to create a query that returns this:

```
[
  { location: { uuid:'3-3'} }
  { location: { uuid:'4-4'} }
]
```

Looks like a job for `aggregate`

Start off by:

```
{ $match: { _id:  123 } }
```

then maybe

```
{ $unwind: '$locations' }
```

then

```
{ $project: { _id: 0, location: '$locations'} }
```

Cool, this gives me:

```
[
  { location: { uuid: '1-1'} }
  { location: { uuid: '2-2'} }
  { location: { uuid: '3-3'} }
  { location: { uuid: '4-4'} }
]
```

Now i need a way to only return elements that come after '3-3' (but also keep 3-3). Any ideas?

Comment: is your locations sorted. from after 3-3 does that mean even if 2-2 is after 3-3 in the array it should be returned

Comment: Yes it's already sorted. uuid is just a random string. Looks like this `f4a2ec87-5c0d-435c-a1a0-4f4bc3e02889`. I just wanted to simplify the example.

Comment: ok then you cannot go in this simplest approach  https://mongoplayground.net/p/jTR44tvXl5F

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: how about this https://mongoplayground.net/p/dzLdpDI8TfO   slicing the array from 2nd index. this way i put unwinds to a later stage after slicing (so less unwinds)

Comment: Super. Thank you. If you pop it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @IvanBacher  Given that the target e.g. `3-3` is an input variable, what behavior do you seek if it is *not* found?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I guess just return all the data in the locations array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the approach I took is to `$slice` the array from index 2 to end of array so to get the position of 3-3 i used `$indexOfArray`.
Now since locations is sliced there is fewer to `$unwind`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "123" } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      locations: {
        $slice: [ "$locations", 
            // If target is not found, $indexOfArray will return -1.
            // OP says in that case, return whole array which means
            // start at 0.
            {$max: [0, { $indexOfArray: [ "$locations", { uuid: "3-3" } ] } ] },
            { $size: "$locations" } ]
        }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$locations" },
  { $project: { _id: 0, location: "$locations" } }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dzLdpDI8TfO)

Comment: Although this answer well-satisfies the OP ask, I would assert that just returning the `$slice`d array is better.  Ultimately same amount of info going across wire but array also gives you length up front; no end-of-cursor surprise.   Also, this would eliminate 2 extra stages that are there for pure formatting, wasting DB server resources.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti some good points there, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works but for extra protection, you might want to do `$indexOfArray` on the `uuid` target, *not* the object:

```
{$max: [0,{ $indexOfArray: [ "$locations.uuid", "3-3"] }] },
```

This ensures correct matching on only `uuid`.  For example, assume the input objects are more complex and possibly polymorphic:

```
{ 
  _id: '123', 
  locations: [ 
    {uuid:'1-1', other:1}, 
    {uuid:'2-2', foo:2}, 
    {uuid:'3-3', baz:3, not_concerned:7}, 
    {uuid:'4-4', corn:4} 
  ] 
}
```

Then the original approach:

```
{ $indexOfArray: [ "$locations", { uuid: "3-3" } ] }
```

will fail because of additional fields `baz` and `not_concerned`.

## Updated

The OP extended the ask in the comments below.   Interestingly enough, the logic to not include the target results in an even simpler stage:

```js
 ,{
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            locations: {$slice: [ "$locations",
                                  {$add:[1,{ $indexOfArray: [ "$locations.uuid", targ]}]},
                                  { $size: "$locations" }
                                ]
                       }
        }
    }
```

Test cases:

- If target is not in list e.g. `99-99` then `$indexOfArray` is -1; `+1` yields 0, so 0 to `$size` yields the whole array as required.
- If target is in list but not last, we properly skip 1 beyond it and return the rest of the list.  **NOTE**: The value of `$size` passed as arg 3 to `$slice` is always the same, regardless of the starting point.  It is OK for this arg to "overrun" the list; the `$slice` will stop when it reaches the end of the input array without error.
- If target is last in list, then `1+$indexOfArray` yields a number equal to `$size` (because index is zero-based), in which case the array is already overrun and `$slice` will return an empty array, as required

Comment: yeah this one is better. didnt realize it myself

Comment: Super, thank you. Out of curiosity what would need to change if the returned array does not need to include the looked for item. E.g. `uuid: 3-3` in `$indexOfArray`, but the results should not include it, only the next items in the array? Essentially if the index is not `-1` then `index + 1` in the `slice` part

Comment: @IvanBacher  What is the behavior if the target is the LAST item in the array?

Comment: If the target is the last item of the array then an empty array should get returned

Comment: @IvanBacher  Answer updated.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Super, thank you. Very interesting

Comment: If the `locations` array is empty then the query results in an error. Using `{ $max: [ 1, { $size: "$locations" } ] }` instead of `{ $size: "$locations" }` in `$slice` seems to overcome this.